# To find the xpath of an Element by identifying the text first in a subclass and then another element in another subclass under same parent

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I basically need to find a sub class under a parent class by identifying a sub class  under the same parent class. it would be great if someone could help.
There are 2 sub classes.First Subclass can be identified for finding the element,then after finding the elements the second subclass can be used

I am trying to find the parent class count first ,then i will try to locate the elements that can be identified in the first subclass and find its position ,ie arrays position and identify the next subclass by this position

Basically 2 subclass under same parent class. i tried by getting the size of the parentclasses, then i wrote a "for loop " for the finding the element in the first subclass and i do not know how to get the location of that subclass in the array, then by getting the position or location i need to find the subsequent subclass[image]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Showing the code is much more understandable than just explaining the problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you.

```
//div[@class='some_class1']///img/following::div
```

Explanation:

Find your class. Then you go deep with any depth you need by each '/' to img. And with /following you will go to the next div in the entire document.